# Communication packet/frames diagram: documenting protocols

Tags: protocols, communication, diagram

Can you suggest me a diagramming software where I can draw diagrams like this one (as much out-of-the-box as possible):
[image]

These type of diagrams are usually used to document communication protocols so one can easily understand how packets/frames are composed.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the best (albeit not the simplest) solution is to draw packet structure diagrams in a vector graphics editor (for example, [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)).

I've stumbled upon this question looking for a solution to the same problem.
And I thought it can be useful to someone else if I share my findings.
Somewhat different PDU structure diagrams can be drawn [with packetdiag](http://blockdiag.com/en/nwdiag/packetdiag-examples.html), [in wavedrom editor](http://wavedrom.com/editor.html) or [described with TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95405/designing-packet-structure-of-a-protocol).

Also, there are some relevant info in answers to related question: <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034636/best-way-to-document-a-packet-protocol</s> (how packet structures are described in RFCs). Question is deleted now, but you can find it [in webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512154204/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034636/best-way-to-document-a-packet-protocol).

It would be great if share the way you solved this problem.